# What this function implies?Why is aAdjusted and bAdjusted?

Tags: solidity, uniswap, ethereumj, timestamp, overflow

````
This function is from uniswap-v3/core/contracts/libraries/Oracle.sol
/// @notice comparator for 32-bit timestamps
/// @dev safe for 0 or 1 overflows, a and b _must_ be chronologically before or equal to time
/// @param time A timestamp truncated to 32 bits
/// @param a A comparison timestamp from which to determine the relative position of `time`
/// @param b From which to determine the relative position of `time`
/// @return bool Whether `a` is chronologically <= `b`
```
function lte(
    uint32 time,
    uint32 a,
    uint32 b
) private pure returns (bool) {
    // if there hasn't been overflow, no need to adjust
    if (a <= time && b <= time) return a <= b;

    uint256 aAdjusted = a > time ? a : a + 2**32;
    uint256 bAdjusted = b > time ? b : b + 2**32;

    return aAdjusted <= bAdjusted;
}
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The block timestamp in Ethereum is the UNIX time — time in seconds since January 1970. When stored as a 32-bit integer, it will overflow some time in the future. After the overflow happens, a UNIX time value `x` may be numerically smaller than a time `y` in the past when compared as 32-bit integer, even though `x` is chronologically after `y`.

The intention of this Solidity code is to make the comparisons of two time values `a` and `b` safe even after the overflow. The value of the current, reference `time` is expected to be chronologically after or equal to the values of `a` and `b`. (This is the assumption this code makes, it will fail it it's not true.) If the value of `a` or/and `b` is greater than the value of `time`, then `time` has overflown, but `a` and/or `b` has not. To correct for this overflow, the max value of unsigned 32-bit integer is added to the variables that have overflown.

Let's say `time = 1`, `a = 0`, `b = 2**32-1`. Then `aAdjusted = 2**32`, `bAdjusted = 2**32-1`, and `aAdjusted` is smaller than `bAdjusted` when compared as 256-bit integers, as expected.